# Flipping between multiple layouts using viewPager? (Android)

Tags: android-viewpager

I'm looking for a way to flip between multiple layouts, where each layout has its own sliding drawer. The best way seemed to be using viewPager, but the examples I've seen showed how to flip between texts and that's not what I really need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my simple project on github http://github.com/shereef
It has a VIewPager and in it a list view similarly you can add a sliding drawer.

Comment: Posted from my mobile reply here for more info and to grab my attention so I can clarify more later